# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'resizable'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I have a page where I need to show a modal. I want to make it re-sizeable but it is not working. Below is all imported js/css files

```
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/App.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/libs/bootbox.min.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/libs/bootstrap-modal.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/libs/bootstrap-transition.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/icheck/jquery.icheck.min.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/select2/select2.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/tableCheckable/jquery.tableCheckable.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/libs/raphael-2.1.2.min.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/demos/dashboard.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" %>'></script>
<script src='<%= RootPath + "/JS/Bootstrap.common.js" %>'></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/icheck/skins/minimal/blue.css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/js/plugins/datepicker/datepicker.css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/BootStrap/js/libs/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css.css">
```

And js code is like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.modal-content').resizable({
        //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
        minHeight: 300,
        minWidth: 300
    });
    $('.modal-dialog').resizable({
        //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
        minHeight: 300,
        minWidth: 300
    });
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();
</script>
```

What is wrong in it?

Answer (score 2):

`resizable()`, along with `draggable()`, are methods of the jQueryUI library; they are not part of standard jQuery.

To solve your problem, you need to include a reference to [jqueryui.js](https://jqueryui.com/) in your page.

Comment: Added below lib, still same issue                                                                            <script src="../Scripts/ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>

Comment: Is the path correct? Did you add it after jQuery.js?Any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, bath is correct.Added after jquery.js. In console same error as above exists

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same errors, turned out the site had some settings in the `_Layout.cshtml` base page that was replacing my latest `jQuery` assemblies with incorrect assemblies.

Check these sections, and any other references, in `_Layout.cshtml`, or whatever base page you use:

```
<environment include="Development">...
<environment exclude="Development">...
```

etc.

Those were wiping my correct assemblies, causing these errors.